# Connect from laravel app in docker container to Postgresql in host machine?

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I've been getting error `SQLSTATE[08006] [7] timeout expired (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from "users")`

I've set the postgresql listen address to `0.0.0.0` but it doesn't sort out

Need better workaround of this

The `.env` file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=172.17.0.1 // <-- this won't connect. I declare like that based on docker0
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=mydb
DB_USERNAME=postgres
DB_PASSWORD=postgres
```

The `docker-compose.yml` file:

```yaml
version: '3'

networks:
  laravel:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  dbdata:
    driver: local

services:
  nginx:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/nginx.dockerfile
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - "${DOCKER_SITE_HOST}:80"
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - php
    networks:
      - laravel

  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/php.dockerfile
    container_name: php
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    networks:
      - laravel

  composer:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/composer.dockerfile
    container_name: composer
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - php
    user: laravel
    entrypoint: [ 'composer', '--ignore-platform-reqs' ]
    networks:
      - laravel

  artisan:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/php.dockerfile
    container_name: artisan
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    user: laravel
    entrypoint: [ 'php', '/var/www/html/artisan' ]
    networks:
      - laravel
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally got it working by using this workaround:

1. allow postgresql host's port
2. change `listen_addresses` config on `postgresql.conf` to `*` hence it becomes `listen_addresses = '*'`
3. put this config on top of the `pg_hba.conf`

```
# TYPE DATABASE USER CIDR-ADDRESS  METHOD
host  all  all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
```

3. restart postgresql
4. and finally use `docker0` interface on `.env`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Open cmd and execute the `ipconfig` command
2. Get your IP ethernet `192.168.x.x`
3. Change the `DB_HOST` Ip to your ethernet Ip in `.env` file
4. Save

The other way is you can get the Ip of running containers using the below command:

`docker inspect -f '{{.Name}} - {{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' $(docker ps -aq)`

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are able to connect to the database and as you point out in the comment on the `.env` file if you use another IP you get a connection error:

```
DB_HOST=172.17.0.1 // <-- this won't connect. I declare like that based on docker0
```

So, because your error is not a connection one and instead is a timeout error, your issue relies in the sql query being to time expensive or your database has a very short timeout for your queries, thus in my opinion is not related to your docker setup.

Answer (score 0):

You have two possibilities:

1. Use inside your laravel docker the same localhost interface that is in your host.
2. Use docker-network.

Considering your docker's localhost is different than your host's localhost, if you want to access `DB_HOST=host.docker.internal`